# How to know when Fragment is closed to process infromation?

Tags: android, android-fragments, broadcastreceiver

So basically i am in Fragment A and i am calling Fragment B, in Fragment B i am processing some information (they are static) and click '**Done**' button that calls `popBackStack()`

Now again i am in Fragment A, but i need to know when user clicked Done in Fragment B, so i know that the  static information is ready.

I guess answer will be some sort of Broadcast Receiver but i cannot get it work yet.

Please give me some ideas?

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by "i need to know when user clicked Done in Fragment B."  If done is a button then I am assuming that you are setting onClickListener on it.  Why not just set a flag in the onClick method?

Comment: I can set static flag in Fragment B and then i need to check in OnResume on Fragment A, so i guess there must be a better solution for this one...

Comment: This will be a very efficient way if you want to stick with using both fragments with one activity.  A better way would be to put fragment A in Activity A and fragment B in activity B.  Then from A, you use   [startActivityForResult](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html)  to launch activity B. In this case your activity A will receive a call back whenever user is done with activity B.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can override the onPause() or onStop() method of your fragment B.